# Numeric Keyboard for Android with Plus(+) char

Tags: android, android-keypad, android-number-picker

I am developing App that has EditText in List Item View. which accept the numeric value and list of values with '+' sign.
on submit a function is called which evaluate that string and adds the values present in that string separated by '+'.
Now the problem is i had set

---

`'inputType="number'`

---

to the EditText box but in numeric keyBoard '+' sign is not present.
I tried to use 'digits=0123456789+' but not worked

Comment: Use `inputType="phone"` or `inputType="textPhonetic`

Comment: Thnx Zubair Ahmad Khan inputType="phone" with digits="0123456789+" solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

> If you'd like an input method for entering a phone number, use the
>   "phone" value:

Use `inputType="phone"`

Reference [here](http://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html)

Answer (score 1):

As Zubair suggested `inputType="phone"` popup perfect keyboard for me.
But to avoid extra character I did use `digits="0123456789+"`

```
<EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/enteramount"
                android:hint="Amount"
                android:textSize="@dimen/Heading"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:digits="0123456789+"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"/>
```

This may be useful to someone.